# Django custom template tag problem

Tags: django

This is my python code for 'box':

```
register = Library()

class KeyNode(Node):
    def __init__(self,  _node):
        self._node = _node,

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            #content = "this works!"
            content = self._node.render(context)
            return content
        except:
            bilogger.exception('KeyNode')
            return ''

@register.tag('box')
def wrapper(parser, token):
    try:
        #fn, _option = token.split_contents()
        node = parser.parse(('endbox',))
        parser.delete_first_token() 
    except ValueError:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("INVALID FORMAT PROVIDED FOR BOX")
    return KeyNode(node)
```

self._node.render(context) is an empty string, and nothing is returned back. However, content = "this works!", works.

Whats wrong here?

Comment: `self._node = _node,` - maybe this is your mistake ? 
`a = 1,` == `(1,)`

Comment: What is the value of `context` in `render()`?

Comment: What is the value of `node`? (just an example would do) And one more question .... What is happening? returning nothing? you might want to remove the try catch to find out what exceptions are occurring.

Comment: @srusskih, you are right! The tuple was causing the problem